# Can I use AND in a SWITCH function in Access?

Tags: database, ms-access

I have created this function to check holiday prices in MS Access:

```
Holiday Price: Switch(
    [Holiday Type]="Single",£1000,
    [Holiday Type]="Couple",£2000,
    [Holiday Type]="Family",£4000
)
```

**This works** but I'd like to add another field (`Activity`) from the table that checks if an activity has been booked. It this field is not empty I want it to return £1200 for Single, £2200 for Couple and £4200 for Family.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am fairly new to databases.

Comment: Why not just try it and find out?

Comment: i did, it kept returning and error, not sure how to embed the AND statement inside this

Comment: If you tried something, and it returned an error, you'd best share that attempt and the error. Then we can see where you went wrong. Of course you can use `AND` in one of the conditions in a `Switch`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Holiday Price: Switch(
    [Holiday Type]="Single", 1000, 
    [Holiday Type]="Couple", 2000,
    [Holiday Type]="Family", 4000) 
    + IIf(Not [Activity] Is Null, IIf([Holiday Type]="Family", 250, 200), 0)
```

Do formatting in textbox to display the currency symbol.

Comment: The Activity column has option in it such as "Swimming ", "Tennis", "Golf" etc. I may try using a nested IIf

Comment: Just tried this still does not work as the "Family" activity goes up by £250 instead of £200 as the others

Comment: Well, your original question showed 200 for all categories. See revised answer.

Comment: Thank, I'll try that :-)